# 2560x1900 from laptop

Tags: resolution

I have a Dell XPS Studio 16 laptop with the ATI Mobility Radeon 4670 display adapter.  The spec for this device say:

The ATI Mobility Radeon™ HD 4600 series GPUs can upscale video display to 2560x1600 on dual-link monitors which is almost twice the display resolution of 1080p displays.

I can't get my Dell 30" 3007WFP monitor to display at this resolution...it's not even listed as an option in the resolution.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What type of connector are you using (i.e. HDMI vs DisplayPort vs VGA etc.)? What operating system do you have? Did you install drivers for that particular monitor?

Comment: Using an HDMI adapter, Windows 7, and yes, the driver is installed for the monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need an adapter from display port to dual link to make use of this resolution.

[Dell Accessories](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/products/cables/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=330-5521)

Comment: It's worth a shot, I don't have a DVI to Display Port adapter, I was hoping to get something to work with HDMI...but maybe it isn't possible.

Comment: I'm sure we can find $99 in the budget for you somewhere.

Comment: Bought the adapter and it worked like a charm.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The [specs page](http://www.amd.com/us/products/notebook/graphics/ati-mobility-hd-4000/hd-4600/Pages/hd-4600-specs.aspx) for ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4600 series says that you can use resolutions of upto 1920x1080 with HDMI output.

> HDMI output support
>
> Supports all display resolutions up to 1920x1080

Comment: Interesting, although I'm only getting 1200x800 resolution to come up...any idea how to get 1920x1080 to come up?